# How do I make the text body go around a tikz picture flushed right?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment

I would like the text to start at the same height as the picture, but I want the picture to be flushed right. It's not directly associated with the text, but rather more like a visualization tool for the text.

Don't worry about the horrible labeling of the nodes. It's just a "hack" until I actually bother fixing the picture so the labelings fit.

```
\begin{flushright}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (a) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (b) at (1.5,0,0);
\coordinate (c) at (0,1.5,0);
\coordinate (d) at (0,0,1.5);
\coordinate (e) at (1.5,1.5,0);
\coordinate (f) at (1.5,0,1.5);
\coordinate (g) at (0,1.5,1.5);
\coordinate (h) at (1.5,1.5,1.5);
\draw[thick] (e)--(c)--(g)--(h)--(e)--(b)--(f)--(d)--(g);
\draw[thick] (h)--(f);
\draw[gray] (b)--(a)--(c);
\draw[gray] (a)--(d);

\node at (a) [left] {$d$};
\node at (b) [right] {$c$};
\node at (c) [above] {$h$};
\node at (d) [left] {$a$};
\node at (e) [above] {$g$};
\node at (f) [right] {$b$};
\node at (g) [above] {$e$};
\node at (h) [above] {$f$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{flushright}

Let $G \subgr S_8$ and $X = \{\{a,g\},\{b,h\},\{c,e\},\{d,f\}\}$
```

Comment: wrapfig and picins do this sort of thing.  There are other ways as well.

Comment: Or just use two `minipage` environments. Or `floatrow`, if you dare. But please post compilable code.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that this code cannot be recommended without a good many caveats and qualifications, warnings and protests, injunctions and admonitions. Not only do I not know what I'm doing, it relies on code marked as experimental by the LaTeX 3 developers. Unlike me, they *do* know what they're doing, so if *they* say *they're* not sure what *they're* doing, it must be true.

Moreover, use of this code will not just screw with the paragraphs where you place an image. It will screw with your entire document. The effects cannot be restricted to a local scope. Destruction is total, doom is universal and annihilation is sure.

## *Caveat emptor ...*

It does seem to work quite nicely, though.

This is based on [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/313434/) to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309302/best-way-to-wrap-text-around-figures-in-expl3) which explicitly asked for a way to do this in `expl3` syntax for use with `xgalley`.

Note that it is the use of `xgalley` which makes this hair-raising. The rest of the `expl3` stuff used here is considered stable.

Or, more accurately, it is the use of `xgalley` which makes this more dodgy than my typical answers which may be hair-raising already since, as I may have mentioned, I don't know what I'm doing.

The code defines two new macros

```
\putright[<untouched lines>](<contents for wrap>}
\putleft[<untouched lines>](<contents for wrap>}
```

The optional argument, if specified, gives the number of complete lines of text at the start of the paragraph before the wrapped figure begins. The default is 2.

I modified the MWE a little, but the key thing is that the number of untouched lines is given as `0` and the picture is specified as the second argument to `\putright` or `\putleft`.

```
\putright[0]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand*\len{1.5}
    \draw [thick] (0,0,\len) coordinate (a) \foreach \i/\j in {(\len,0,\len)/b,(\len,0,0)/c,(\len,\len,0)/g,(0,\len,0)/h,(0,\len,\len)/e,(\len,\len,\len)/f} {-- \i coordinate (\j)} -- (g) (f) -- (b) (a) -- (e);
    \coordinate (d) at (0,0,0);
    \draw [gray] (a) -- (d) edge (c) -- (h);
    \foreach \i/\j in {a/left,b/right,c/right,d/left,e/left,f/right,g/above,h/above} \node at (\i) [\j] {\i};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
Let $G S_8$ and $X = \{\{a,g\},\{b,h\},\{c,e\},\{d,f\}\}$\par
\kant[1-2]
```

I added some extra Kant to satisfy the metaphysical curiosities of the interested.

Here's another example from my earlier answer.

```
\putright[4]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}}
\kant[3-4]
```

Here's the result:

[image: ducks and cubes (one of each, anyway)]

A double-page spread:

[image: ducks and cubes (two apiece)]

## Complete code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,xgalley,tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_xwrapfig_fig_box
\box_new:N \l_xwrapfig_vfig_box
\box_new:N \l_xwrapfig_hfig_box
\dim_new:N \l_xwrapfig_wd_dim
\dim_new:N \l_xwrapfig_totalht_dim
\dim_new:N \l_xwrapfig_adjwd_dim
\clist_new:N \l_xwrapfig_indents_clist
\int_new:N \l_xwrapfig_lines_int
\int_new:N \l_xwrapfig_totallines_int
\int_new:N \l_xwrapfig_adjlines_int
\fp_new:N \l_xwrapfig_adjfig_fp
\dim_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_adjwd_dim { 2ex }
\int_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_adjlines_int { 1 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \galley_cutout_right:nn { nV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \galley_cutout_left:nn { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xwrapfig_prewrap:n
{
  \clist_clear:N \l_xwrapfig_indents_clist
  \vbox_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_vfig_box { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_totalht_dim { \box_ht:N \l_xwrapfig_vfig_box + \box_dp:N \l_xwrapfig_vfig_box }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_hfig_box { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_wd_dim { \box_wd:N \l_xwrapfig_hfig_box + \l_xwrapfig_adjwd_dim }
  \int_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_totallines_int { ( \l_xwrapfig_totalht_dim / \baselineskip ) + \l_xwrapfig_adjlines_int }
  \int_zero:N \l_xwrapfig_lines_int
  \int_do_while:nn { \l_xwrapfig_lines_int < \l_xwrapfig_totallines_int }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_xwrapfig_lines_int
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l_xwrapfig_indents_clist { \l_xwrapfig_wd_dim }
  }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xwrapfig_postwrap:
{
  \box_set_ht:Nn \l_xwrapfig_fig_box { 0pt }
  \box_set_dp:Nn \l_xwrapfig_fig_box { 0pt }
  \box_use:N \l_xwrapfig_fig_box
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xwrapfig_putright:nn
{
  \xwrapfig_prewrap:n { #2 }
  \galley_cutout_right:nV { #1 } \l_xwrapfig_indents_clist
  \vbox_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_fig_box
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_adjfig_fp { ( #1 + .5\l_xwrapfig_adjlines_int ) * \baselineskip }
    \skip_vertical:n  { \fp_to_dim:N \l_xwrapfig_adjfig_fp }
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { \linewidth } { \skip_horizontal:n { \linewidth - \l_xwrapfig_wd_dim + .5\l_xwrapfig_adjwd_dim } #2 }
  }
  \xwrapfig_postwrap:
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xwrapfig_putleft:nn
{
  \xwrapfig_prewrap:n { #2 }
  \galley_cutout_left:nV { #1 } \l_xwrapfig_indents_clist
  \vbox_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_fig_box
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_adjfig_fp { ( #1 + .5\l_xwrapfig_adjlines_int ) * \baselineskip }
    \skip_vertical:n  { \fp_to_dim:N \l_xwrapfig_adjfig_fp }
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { \l_xwrapfig_wd_dim } { \skip_horizontal:n { .5\l_xwrapfig_adjwd_dim } #2 }
  }
  \xwrapfig_postwrap:
}
\NewDocumentCommand\putright { O { 2 } +m }
{
  \xwrapfig_putright:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\putleft { O { 2 } +m }
{
  \xwrapfig_putleft:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\putright[0]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand*\len{1.5}
    \draw [thick] (0,0,\len) coordinate (a) \foreach \i/\j in {(\len,0,\len)/b,(\len,0,0)/c,(\len,\len,0)/g,(0,\len,0)/h,(0,\len,\len)/e,(\len,\len,\len)/f} {-- \i coordinate (\j)} -- (g) (f) -- (b) (a) -- (e);
    \coordinate (d) at (0,0,0);
    \draw [gray] (a) -- (d) edge (c) -- (h);
    \foreach \i/\j in {a/left,b/right,c/right,d/left,e/left,f/right,g/above,h/above} \node at (\i) [\j] {\i};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
Let $G S_8$ and $X = \{\{a,g\},\{b,h\},\{c,e\},\{d,f\}\}$\par
\kant[1-2]

\putleft[3]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}}
\kant[3]
\clearpage

\putleft[0]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand*\len{1.5}
    \draw [thick] (0,0,\len) coordinate (a) \foreach \i/\j in {(\len,0,\len)/b,(\len,0,0)/c,(\len,\len,0)/g,(0,\len,0)/h,(0,\len,\len)/e,(\len,\len,\len)/f} {-- \i coordinate (\j)} -- (g) (f) -- (b) (a) -- (e);
    \coordinate (d) at (0,0,0);
    \draw [gray] (a) -- (d) edge (c) -- (h);
    \foreach \i/\j in {a/left,b/right,c/right,d/left,e/left,f/right,g/above,h/above} \node at (\i) [\j] {\i};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
Let $G S_8$ and $X = \{\{a,g\},\{b,h\},\{c,e\},\{d,f\}\}$\par
\kant[4]

\putright{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}}
\kant[5]

\end{document}
```