# Best way to wrap text around figures in expl3

Tags: expl3, latex3, wrap, l3galley, xgalley

As remarked in [another question from today](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309227/xgalley-breaks-spacing-around-lists), I am trying to find a more flexible way to get text wrapped around figures than standard solutions like `wrapfig` or manual use of `\parshape`, and my eyes are currently focused on the experimental expl3 package `xgalley`.

One of the issues is how to place the figure on the right of the text.
My first attempts, shown below, use a not very pure mixture of plain TeX commands and expl3. **Is there a more “correct” and “pure”, preferably expl3-based approach to placing the figure on the right?**

There are alse several problems with the current construction, including the fact that it uses `\vadjust`, which is likely to mess up the mechanisms from `xgalley`. Also, I was unable to make the content of `\putright` top-aligned (`\vtop` messed everything up), so the first argument of `\putright` (the number of lines to lower the figure) has to be higher than the one passed to `\cutright`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,xgalley,graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \cutright \galley_cutout_right:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\putright[2]{% #1 = number of lines to lower the figure, #2 = content
    \leavevmode
    \vadjust{%
        \hfill
        \smash{%
            \lower\dimexpr#1\baselineskip-2.5\lineskip\relax\llap{#2}%
        }%
    }\ignorespaces
}

\begin{document}


\cutright{4}{.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth}
\putright{12}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 'LaTeX3' is nothing like available: presumably you want some `expl3`-based code to do what you have in primitives.

Comment: You might consider this a “best practises” question.

Comment: A better wrapfig would be neat. I once tried to adapt it to have some full lines before the cut and had a lot of problems.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer As I am sure you know much more about than I, you can get quite far with `\parshape`, if you are willing to make thousands of small manual adjustments.

Comment: @Gaussler Thank for inspiration. I've created a new OPmac trick 0154 http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#setparshape and 0155 http://petr.olsak.net/opmac-tricks-e.html#putshape where the problem is solved.

Comment: @cfr The entire point of the `cutout` data type is that it is for things that are of fixed size and so do not respect paragraphs.

Comment: @JosephWright I probably asked the wrong question. How do I stop it repeating, sometimes several paragraphs later? Or is `cutout` intended only for shapes which should repeat? If so, how is the pattern of repetition determined? It seems odd, for example, that if I have a left `cutout` and then a right one and then a regular paragraph and then a few more paragraphs, the few more paragraphs may use the left `cutout` shape. What's the rule for when the changed indentation gets repeated? And what should be used for a one-off `cutout` which may span paragraphs?

Comment: @JosephWright To put this another way, in my answer, I need `\resetindents` once but only once. I could understand if I needed it after each `cutout` which should be followed by a regular paragraph. Or if I needed it after each `cutout` to avoid accumulation. Or if I didn't need it at all. But I can't figure out why I need it only in certain cases. And I can't figure out how to do it automatically, but maybe that's not intended to be possible.

Comment: @Gaussler Do you have an MWE? As you know, `xgalley` is still experimental and changes the output routine rather radically.

Comment: @wipet I tried using your OPmac solutions in a simple LaTeX document, but it crashed of course because the formats are very different. Would it be possible to adapt the solutions to the LaTeX setting to obtain a more flexible `wrapfig` replacement?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want the syntax shown in the question, see my original answer below.

This edit revises the user interface and eliminates the need to use `\cutright` before `\putright`. This version also produces a tidier result and is, I think, less incorrect than my first attempt.

The new version defines *only* the following commands:

```
\putright[<options>]{<content for cut-out>}
\putleft[<options>]{<content for cut-out>}
\resetindents
\xwrapfigsetup{<options>}
```

`<options>` are defined using a key-value interface. `\xwrapfigsetup{}` knows exactly one key, `cutout` which itself takes a list of default options for cutouts created with `\putright` and `\putleft`. `\putright` and `\putleft` know about slightly more keys:

```
hmargin=<dimension>
```

which specifies the total horizontal space left to the left and right of the content of the cutout (default is 2ex);

```
skip lines=<integer>
```

which specifies the number of lines to allow for the cutout in addition to those required to fit the content (default is 1);

```
top lines=<integer>
```

which specifies the number of unaltered lines to leave at the top of the paragraph before the cutout (default is 2).

The rest is handled automatically or not at all, with the rather large exception of restoring standard paragraph shape after the cutout is typeset.

`\putright`/`\putleft` calculate an appropriate number of lines to indent and the width required for the indents. They then add the cutout to the current paragraph and finally typeset the content of the cutout.

This means that simply saying

```
\putright{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}}
\lipsum
```

produces

[image: duck out on right]

Similarly,

```
\putleft[top lines=3]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}}
\kant[3]
```

[image: duck left]

The additional line skipped allows a little head and tail room for the duck. Obviously, this can be amended if you would prefer a tighter or looser fit.

Complete code (earlier version in [my answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/296570/how-do-i-make-the-text-body-go-around-a-tikz-picture-flushed-right/313808#313808):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,xgalley,tikz}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\box_new:N \l_xwrapfig_fig_box
\box_new:N \l_xwrapfig_vfig_box
\box_new:N \l_xwrapfig_hfig_box
\dim_new:N \l_xwrapfig_wd_dim
\dim_new:N \l_xwrapfig_totalht_dim
\clist_new:N \l_xwrapfig_indents_clist
\int_new:N \l_xwrapfig_lines_int
\int_new:N \l_xwrapfig_totallines_int
\fp_new:N \l_xwrapfig_adjfig_fp
\keys_define:nn { xwrapfig }
{
  cutout .code:n = {
    \keys_set:nn { xwrapfig / cutout } { #1 }
  }
}
\keys_define:nn { xwrapfig / cutout }
{
  hmargin .dim_set:N = \l_xwrapfig_adjwd_dim,
  hmargin .initial:n = { 2ex },
  skip~lines .int_set:N = \l_xwrapfig_adjlines_int,
  skip~lines .initial:n = { 1 },
  top~lines .int_set:N = \l_xwrapfig_toplines_int,
  top~lines .initial:n = { 2 },
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \galley_cutout_right:nn { nV }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \galley_cutout_left:nn { nV }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xwrapfig_prewrap:n
{
  \clist_clear:N \l_xwrapfig_indents_clist
  \clist_clear:N \l_xwrapfig_zindents_clist
  \vbox_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_vfig_box { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_totalht_dim { \box_ht:N \l_xwrapfig_vfig_box + \box_dp:N \l_xwrapfig_vfig_box }
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_hfig_box { #1 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_wd_dim { \box_wd:N \l_xwrapfig_hfig_box + \l_xwrapfig_adjwd_dim }
  \int_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_totallines_int { ( \l_xwrapfig_totalht_dim / \baselineskip ) + \l_xwrapfig_adjlines_int }
  \int_zero:N \l_xwrapfig_lines_int
  \int_do_while:nn { \l_xwrapfig_lines_int < \l_xwrapfig_totallines_int }
  {
    \int_incr:N \l_xwrapfig_lines_int
    \clist_put_right:Nn \l_xwrapfig_indents_clist { \l_xwrapfig_wd_dim }
  }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xwrapfig_postwrap:
{
  \box_set_ht:Nn \l_xwrapfig_fig_box { 0pt }
  \box_set_dp:Nn \l_xwrapfig_fig_box { 0pt }
  \skip_vertical:n { -\baselineskip }
  \box_use:N \l_xwrapfig_fig_box
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xwrapfig_putright:nn
{
  \xwrapfig_prewrap:n { #2 }
  \galley_cutout_right:nV { #1 } \l_xwrapfig_indents_clist
  \vbox_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_fig_box
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_adjfig_fp { ( #1 + .5\l_xwrapfig_adjlines_int ) * \baselineskip }
    \skip_vertical:n  { \fp_to_dim:N \l_xwrapfig_adjfig_fp }
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { \linewidth } { \skip_horizontal:n { \linewidth - \l_xwrapfig_wd_dim + .5\l_xwrapfig_adjwd_dim } #2 }
  }
  \xwrapfig_postwrap:
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \xwrapfig_putleft:nn
{
  \xwrapfig_prewrap:n { #2 }
  \galley_cutout_left:nV { #1 } \l_xwrapfig_indents_clist
  \vbox_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_fig_box
  {
    \fp_set:Nn \l_xwrapfig_adjfig_fp { ( #1 + .5\l_xwrapfig_adjlines_int ) * \baselineskip }
    \skip_vertical:n  { \fp_to_dim:N \l_xwrapfig_adjfig_fp }
    \hbox_to_wd:nn { \l_xwrapfig_wd_dim } { \skip_horizontal:n { .5\l_xwrapfig_adjwd_dim } #2 }
  }
  \xwrapfig_postwrap:
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xwrapfig_putleft:nn { Vn }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xwrapfig_putright:nn { Vn }
\NewDocumentCommand\putright { O { } +m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { xwrapfig / cutout } { #1 }
  \xwrapfig_putright:Vn \l_xwrapfig_toplines_int { #2 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\putleft { O { } +m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { xwrapfig / cutout } { #1 }
  \xwrapfig_putleft:Vn \l_xwrapfig_toplines_int { #2 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand\resetindents { }
{
  \galley_parshape_set_multi:nnnN { 0 } { 0pt } { 0pt } \c_true_bool
}
\NewDocumentCommand\xwrapfigsetup { m }
{
  \keys_set:nn { xwrapfig } { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\kant[1]

\putright[top lines=0]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand*\len{1.5}
    \draw [thick] (0,0,\len) coordinate (a) \foreach \i/\j in {(\len,0,\len)/b,(\len,0,0)/c,(\len,\len,0)/g,(0,\len,0)/h,(0,\len,\len)/e,(\len,\len,\len)/f} {-- \i coordinate (\j)} -- (g) (f) -- (b) (a) -- (e);
    \coordinate (d) at (0,0,0);
    \draw [gray] (a) -- (d) edge (c) -- (h);
    \foreach \i/\j in {a/left,b/right,c/right,d/left,e/left,f/right,g/above,h/above} \node at (\i) [\j] {\i};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
Let $G S_8$ and $X = \{\{a,g\},\{b,h\},\{c,e\},\{d,f\}\}$
\kant[1-2]

\kant[3]
\clearpage

\putright[top lines=0]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand*\len{1.5}
    \draw [thick] (0,0,\len) coordinate (a) \foreach \i/\j in {(\len,0,\len)/b,(\len,0,0)/c,(\len,\len,0)/g,(0,\len,0)/h,(0,\len,\len)/e,(\len,\len,\len)/f} {-- \i coordinate (\j)} -- (g) (f) -- (b) (a) -- (e);
    \coordinate (d) at (0,0,0);
    \draw [gray] (a) -- (d) edge (c) -- (h);
    \foreach \i/\j in {a/left,b/right,c/right,d/left,e/left,f/right,g/above,h/above} \node at (\i) [\j] {\i};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
Let $G S_8$ and $X = \{\{a,g\},\{b,h\},\{c,e\},\{d,f\}\}$
\kant[1-2]

\putleft[top lines=3]{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}}
\kant[3]
\clearpage

\putleft[top lines=0]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \newcommand*\len{1.5}
    \draw [thick] (0,0,\len) coordinate (a) \foreach \i/\j in {(\len,0,\len)/b,(\len,0,0)/c,(\len,\len,0)/g,(0,\len,0)/h,(0,\len,\len)/e,(\len,\len,\len)/f} {-- \i coordinate (\j)} -- (g) (f) -- (b) (a) -- (e);
    \coordinate (d) at (0,0,0);
    \draw [gray] (a) -- (d) edge (c) -- (h);
    \foreach \i/\j in {a/left,b/right,c/right,d/left,e/left,f/right,g/above,h/above} \node at (\i) [\j] {\i};
  \end{tikzpicture}}
Let $G S_8$ and $X = \{\{a,g\},\{b,h\},\{c,e\},\{d,f\}\}$\par
\kant[4]

\putright{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}}
\kant[5]
\resetindents

\xwrapfigsetup{%
  cutout={%
    skip lines=3,
    hmargin=5ex,
    top lines=1,
  }
}

\kant[6]

\kant[7]

\putright{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}}
\kant[5]


\end{document}
```

[image: ducks and cubes]

Note that it isn't clear to me how to apply this only to the current block of text. There is something very odd about the way this works. I tried to use `\galley_parshape_set_single:nVVN` but I could only get that to work properly for `\putleft`.

`\resetindents` is, therefore, provided to reset the paragraph indentation. This needs to come after the `\putleft` or `\putright` is used.

What I don't understand is why the second paragraph of, say, `\kant[1-2]` isn't affected, but a subsequent `\kant[3]` is (as [wipet points out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309302/best-way-to-wrap-text-around-figures-in-expl3/313434?noredirect=1#comment765160_313434)) or why a left cutout space is repeated several paragraphs after it was last used.

I suspect there's something fundamental about how this is meant to be done which I just don't get at the moment.

## Original answer

Do you want something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum,xgalley,graphicx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% don't use \cs_new_eq for document-level macros (which necessarily fail to conform to expl3 syntax) - use xparse
\NewDocumentCommand\cutright { m m }
{
  \galley_cutout_right:nn { #1 } { #2 }
}
\coffin_new:N \l_gaussler_fig_coffin
\box_new:N \l_gaussler_fig_box
\NewDocumentCommand\putright { m m }
{
  \vbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { #2 }
  \dim_set:Nn \l_tmpa_dim { \box_dp:N \l_tmpa_box + \box_ht:N \l_tmpa_box }
  \int_set:Nn \l_tmpa_int { ( #1 - ( \l_tmpa_dim / \baselineskip ) ) /2 }
  \skip_vertical:n { #1\baselineskip - \l_tmpa_dim +\l_tmpa_int\baselineskip }
  \skip_horizontal:N \linewidth
  \vbox_to_zero:n
  {
    \hbox_overlap_left:n { #2 }
  }
  \skip_vertical:n { -#1\baselineskip + \l_tmpa_dim - \l_tmpa_int\baselineskip  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}


\cutright{4}{.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth,.35\textwidth}
\putright{9}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{duck}}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image: confused duck]

Comment: I think part of why I split `\cutright` and `\putright` into two macros in the MWE was to keep things simple and “minimal”. I certainly planned to put both into a single wrapper command in my own preamble. Obviously, we also need a `\putleft` command, but I assume that is just a matter of modifying your code. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @Gaussler Just be a little careful. Because, I assume, of the way `xgalley` works, it isn't possible to use a group within the definition of `\putright` to limit the effects of the code. This is why I created so many `\l_gausserl_...` variables rather than using the `\l_tmp...` versions, even when the latter seemed quite sufficient to the purpose. I thought it might be safer not to change them in case you used them elsewhere.

Comment: @Gaussler You might want to use the latest version above. It seems slightly more reliable.

Comment: @Gaussler Please see edit for `\putleft` etc.

Comment: I tried your "complete code" and I don't understand two things. 1 why there is a vertical space between paragraphs? 2. When I remove (comment out) the `\putleft[3]{...}` between `\kant[1-2]` and `\kant[3]`, then the vertical space is removed, but there is an accidental cropping of the text which repeates the cropping from the beginning of the document.

Comment: @cfr It is quite a promising piece of code. If we add in a keyval syntax to control padding and perhaps add a way to make a caption, this could become quite a nice new `xwrapfig` package.

Comment: If that happens, then it should probably also be an environment instead of a command.

Comment: @Gaussler This is nowhere near ready for anybody to use. See wipet's comments and those are only two of the issues :(.

Comment: @wipet Thanks. Yes. There are numerous problems with this. I've added `\resetindents` as a workaround for the spurious indentation, but that is only one of the issues. 'Complete' is only meant to indicate it is a complete example. There's no need to put it in scare quotes.

Comment: @cfr I think those are simply bugs in `xgalley` which should be reported.

Comment: @cfr These are not "scare quotes". I meant this only as "technical quotes" in order to distinguish two codes in your answer: "original answer" and "complete code".

Comment: @wipet Oh, fair enough. Sorry - I misunderstood.

Comment: @Gaussler Please see edit. I'm an idiot. I realised where the vertical spacing is coming from so I made the correction. (At least, I think I understand where it is coming from.)

Comment: @wipet I guess the vertical spacing is from the way I introduce the box, so adjusting for that seems reasonable. I still don't know how to limit it to a single paragraph, though.

Comment: @cfr Upvoting for the sentence “I’m an idiot”. ;-)

Comment: BTW, this answer gets a bounty in 24 hours; I cannot award it yet for some reason.

Comment: @Gaussler You're giving a bounty to somebody you agree is an idiot? :-)

Comment: Yes, I am awarding you for having self-awareness. :-)

Comment: @Gaussler You may change your mind in light of my latest edit, of course.

Comment: @cfr Obviously, I am awarding you the bounty for an exceptionally useful answer with great potential. :-) Don’t mind my jokes. ;-)

Comment: @cfr Also, isn’t it a tiny bit artificial to have a single key in `\xwrapfigsetup` which has its own key value interface? Why not move that interface out to `\xwrapfigsetup` itself?

Comment: @Gaussler The thought was that if this did eventually get expanded, you might want it to support more things than cutouts. If not, though, you can just define the various keys directly for `xwrapfig` and do away with the `/ cutout` completely.

Comment: @Gaussler Thanks for the bounty. I hope this proves usable sometime!

Comment: @cfr It surely will! However, `xgalley` still breaks lots of things, so it might take some time until it can be used for big-scale projects.

Comment: @Gaussler Yes. `xgalley` is not really usable right now except in the most limited way. Not for 'real' documents, I mean.

Comment: It seems, unfortunately, that TL18 has made xgalley useless. When I try loading it, `expl3` complains about undefined commands.

Comment: @Gaussler The usual solution in such cases is to blame David. Technically, this isn't actually a solution, but it still seems to be the one people try every time. Have you tried reporting it?

Answer (score 4):

I don't understand two things. Why do you need explicitly expl3 solution when solution based on TeX primitives is more simple and more straightforward. And why you are using different data in `\cutright` and `\putright`. First parameter (4) denotes the number of untouched lines but second (12) -- I don't know what it is.

I am able to help you with the second thing. Define:

```
\def\putright#1#2{\vskip\parskip
   \hbox to\hsize{\hss
      \vbox to0pt{\kern#1\baselineskip\kern-.8\baselineskip \hbox{#2}\vss}}
   \nobreak\vskip-\parskip\vskip-\baselineskip
}
```

Then you can use the same data for both: `\cutright{4}{...}\putright{4}{...}`.

Comment: Well, part of why I wanted an expl3 solution was because `xgalley` actually supports figures spanning multilple paragraphs, something which is very hard to do in 2e.

Comment: @Gaussler I think the point is that wipet would recommend not using LaTeX of any kind. Though I do think that 'simple' and 'straightforward' are very much in the eyes of the beholder: what is simplest and most straightforward for anybody tends to be what that person is most familiar with ;).

Comment: @Gaussler And, of course, part of the ultimate goal of L3 is, as I understand it, to provide a language which means you don't need to use the lower level TeX stuff, as you do with 2e. So the simple/straightforward aspect will change a bit when L3 matures as LaTeX will then be more of a genuine alternative, rather than needing to be a convenient addition. At least, I guess that's part of the idea. (Of course, it will still ultimately rely on TeX.)

Comment: @cfr The main problem of L3 is the goal described in your comment: to give different language than TeX but to use TeX. Why not to use the same language as understands the used interpreter? If you learn only a different language than used in the interpreter then you will never understand the interpreter well (tracing, error messages etc.). My idea is: use only the same language as the interpreter is using and you will be happy without any problems. As me. This is more "straightforward" (independent of the beholder). Unfortunately, L2e is very bad example of mixing various approaches.

Comment: But you are very, very, very experienced with TeX. I'm not and the code is very difficult to learn because there is no pattern to it in the way there is to L3. You can't guess the name or meaning of a macro, for example. It is great that you are so comfortable with TeX. But it is not at all straightforward for the rest of us!

Comment: @wipet I’ll have to agree with cfr; while your OPmac trick list is extraordinarily impressive and shows the true strengths of TeX, to me, the code is completely unintelligible. It looks like a beautiful language with its own special kind of spirit, logic, and humour; but it seems to have a learning curve close to that of a very complicated natural language like Hungarian.

Comment: @wipet Regarding the different arguments, it was simply because I could not get `\vtop` to work in the original construction, meaning that I could not make the figure top-aligned. Therefore, I had to use this seemingly arbitrary number `12` in the argument.